# Golang: архитектура системы обработки задач по интервалам

Tags: postgresql, golang, архитектура, rabbitmq

У нас есть большой список сайтов и команд, которые нужно выполнить на этом сайте через заданный интервал в нашей базе данных.

Таблица: ID, САЙТ, КОМАНДЫ (json: имя_команды => интервал минут)

```
1, example1.ru, { "имя_команды1": 5, "имя_команды2": 5, "имя_команды3": 60}
```

Также есть консольное приложение, которое может выполнять различные задачи на сайте. Например:

Проверить статус ответа
Проверка сертификатов HTTPS
Поиск некоторых данных в содержании
и т. д.
Нам нужно спроектировать приложение Golang таким образом, чтобы его можно было легко масштабировать (т.е. создавать несколько экземпляров приложения на разных машинах).

Хотелось бы понять, как лучше организовать архитектуру? Таблица в базе данных является примером структуры. Возможно, его нужно организовать иначе, для более эффективного использования.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с оформлением, и опишите, что и как организовать.

Я вижу этот вариант:

Подключаю rabbitmq — он будет выступать в роли очереди задач на выполнение.
Голанг будет работать:
Потребитель, который слушает очередь задач, берет задачу и передает ее внутренним воркерам (горутинам) для выполнения. После выполнения дата последнего выполнения будет отмечена в базе данных.

Отдельная горутина, которая раз в минуту сканирует базу данных, ищет невыполненные задачи и ставит их в очередь на выполнение. В БД создается отметка о том, что задача снята с исполнения (т.е. задача блокируется).

Comment: Можно и через RabbitMQ, или через [Gearman](https://github.com/mikespook/gearman-go), суть вы уже уловили - добавлять задачи в очередь, из которой они будут распределяться на обработку рабочим процессам. Можно пойти и дальше, реализовав этот механизм в одном процессе, используя [goroutine и channel](https://github.com/alitto/pond).